# set_include_path doesn't work with parent directory?

Tags: php, include-path, php-include

I'm trying to run a file - test.php - from /home/neubert.  In /home/neubert I have an admin directory. So it seems like if I set the include path to be /home/neubert/admin and then do fopen() on ../test.php that that should resolve to /home/neubert/admin/../test.php and that that should work. But it isn't.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
set_include_path(__DIR__ . '/admin/');

$fp = fopen('../test.php', 'r');
if (!$fp) {
   exit("failed to open\r\n");
}
echo fread($fp, 1024);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd say it probably has to do with relative paths being applied only from the working directory, and not from the path variable (take into account that the path may contain numerous directories and not only one).

Comment: Where is this script located which you show us now? Also do you include this code into another script?(e.g. your wrote this code in x/y/z/index.php, but you include it into /x/y/test.php) Also add error reporting and tell us if you get any errors: `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>`